# Consistently space text in center of images regardless of height

Tags: html, css, image, sass, flexbox

I am trying to create a portfolio grid that consists of divs that hold an image with text underneath. I want to keep the text spacing consistent from the center of the image regardless of the image height (as they vary).

It is currently looking like this: https://gyazo.com/21c53003306409e19d23dad3cb470c29

But I would like it to look like this: https://gyazo.com/68404d8c6e07f5c37d60ecd05d844fbf

The way I achieved the example I want it to look like is by setting "margin: -37px" but it has 2 issues, the first is I would have to set that for every image/case study feature. The second being that, as I resize, the text slowly becomes out of line as the images adjust, making the 37px variance no longer correct.

Not sure if there is a simple solution or not. I want the images to remain the same size as each other, but have no control over the original file dimensions.

```css
// .case-container {
//     display: flex;
//     width: 1200px;
//     margin-top: 100px;
//     margin-bottom: 100px;
//     text-align: center;
//     justify-content: space-between;
//     flex-wrap: wrap;

//     @media (max-width: 1330px) {
//     width: 80%;
//     } 

    
// }

// .header-row {
//     width: 100%;
// }

// .case-column {
    
// }

// .case-image {
   
//     width: 400px;
//     height: 400px;
//     justify-content: center;
//     align-items: center;
    
// }



// .image-cover {
//     width: 100%;
// }


// .case-container {
//     max-width: 1400px;
// }

// .header-row {
//     flex: 1;
//     text-align: center;
// }

// .case-columns {
//     display: flex;
//     text-align: center;
//     justify-content: space-between;
//     align-items: center;
//     flex-basis: 40%;
// }



// .case-column-1 {    //This controls how much each case will take up of the column compared to the other column
//     flex: 1;
//     display: flex;
//     flex-direction: column;
// }

// .case-column-2 {    //This controls how much each case will take up of the column compared to the other column
//     flex: 1;
//     display: flex;
//     flex-direction: column;
// }

// .case-1 {   //This controls how much each case will take up of the column
//     flex: 1;
// }

// .case-2 {   //This controls how much each case will take up of the column
//     flex: 1;
// }

// .case-image { //This controls the image size
//     width: 100%;
// }


.case-container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    min-width: 400px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.case-row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.feature-case {
    // flex-direction: column;
    // align-items: space-between;
    flex-basis: 48%;
    flex: 1;
}

.case-image {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.inner-case-image {
    width: 75%;
}

.case-text {
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="case-container">
            <div class="header-row">
                <h3>Case Studies</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="case-grid">
                <div class="case-row">
                    <div class="feature-case">
                        <div class="case-image">
                            <img class="inner-case-image" src="https://i.gyazo.com/16aff212400b8d6de10246f5003116e0.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="case-text">
                            <h4>UI/UX | MOBILE APP</h4>
                            <h3>Conseris Data Collection App</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="feature-case">
                        <div class="case-image image-spacing">
                            <img class="inner-case-image" src="https://i.gyazo.com/0573b6396a2447858cc65723f391933a.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="case-text">
                            <h4>UI/UX | MOBILE APP</h4>
                            <h3>Conseris Data Collection App</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="case-row">
                    <div class="feature-case">
                        <div class="case-image">
                            <img class="inner-case-image" src="https://i.gyazo.com/16aff212400b8d6de10246f5003116e0.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="case-text">
                            <h4>UI/UX | MOBILE APP</h4>
                            <h3>Conseris Data Collection App</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="feature-case">
                        <div class="case-image">
                            <img class="inner-case-image" src="https://i.gyazo.com/0573b6396a2447858cc65723f391933a.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="case-text">
                            <h4>UI/UX | MOBILE APP</h4>
                            <h3>Conseris Data Collection App</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="case-button">

            </div>


        </div>
```

The code is messy as I am just getting into my first real full-site creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a max-height value on class 'case-image' that matches the height of your shortest image.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it out my friend, the problem here are the pictures. Even when setting a max height for case-row and feature-case the problem was still there.

Fixed it when I set a max height for the picture as you can see below:

```
 .inner-case-image {
   width: 75%;
   max-height: 350px;
 }
```

Test it out.